# Matplotlib: How to plot an empty circle in an scatter plot using pandas plot api?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I'm trying to plot a scatter plot with pandas api where each point is an empty circle, just with border color and transparency. I've tried a lot of tweaks in this code:

```
 ax = ddf.plot.scatter(
        x='espvida', 
        y='e_anosestudo', 
        c=ddf['cor'],
        alpha=.2,
        marker='o');
```

The generated plot looks like this:

[image: Scatter plot]

If you look closely at the points:

[image: filled points]

you'll see that they have a transparent fill color and a border. I'd like it to have just a transparent border. Hou would I do it?

Comment: I'm asking using pandas api. It looks like there is a bug in the api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't seem to get it to work with `DataFrame.plot.scatter`; it doesn't seem to respect the `facecolors='none'` kwarg, likely because some default color argument is being passed to `plt.scatter`.

Instead, fall back to `matplotlib`, specifying `facecolors='none'` and setting the `edgecolors` to the column in your `df` that represents the color.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.normal(1,1,1000),
                   'y': np.random.normal(1,1,1000),
                   'color': list('rgby')*250})

plt.scatter(df.x.values, df.y.values, facecolors='none', edgecolors=df['color'], alpha=0.2, s=100)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

From the [matplotlib scatter doc](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html):

> edgecolors : color or sequence of color, optional, default: 'face'. The edge color of the marker. Possible values:
>
> - 'face': The edge color will always be the same as the face color.
> - 'none': No patch boundary will be drawn.
> - A matplotib color.
>
> For non-filled markers, the edgecolors kwarg is ignored and forced to 'face' internally

Try add: `edgecolors='none'`:

```
 ax = ddf.plot.scatter(
        x='espvida', 
        y='e_anosestudo', 
        c=ddf['cor'],
        alpha=.2,
        marker='o',
        edgecolors='none);
```